# How can I use CodeIgniter ACL library?

Tags: php, codeigniter, acl

How can I implement an ACL library? What is the best way for using ACL for user roles? In standard PHP, I'd write code like this:

```
if (userTypeId == 'Admin') {
  hello Admin
} else if (userTypeId == 'Member') {
   hello member
}
```

How would you do this using CodeIgniter?

Comment: Please use Ion Auth library and `in_group` function for ACL (http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/#in_group), it lightweight Auth library

Answer (score 10):

You can start working with [Bonfire](http://cibonfire.com/) for ACL with codeigniter.

It is a ready to use Codeigniter framework with some additional functionalities. It contains User registration, authentication, and Role-Base Access Control....

Download link:

https://github.com/ci-bonfire/Bonfire/archive/master.zip

Documentation for working with user permissions and roles in bonfire:

http://cibonfire.com/docs/bonfire/roles_and_permissions

Comment: Please link to the repo instead of the zip file directly

Comment: @mopsyd, here you go: https://github.com/ci-bonfire/Bonfire

Answer (score 4):

You can find lot of links for tutorial while searching in google.

1. http://www.tastybytes.net/blog/simple-acl-class-for-codeigniter
2. https://code.google.com/p/ar-acl/
3. https://github.com/brandesign/CodeIgniter-ACL   // contains implementation

In SO also,
[how to use this simple acl library into codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12079843/how-to-use-this-simple-acl-library-into-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0):

My preference on this is to pull in one of the Zend Framework modules. I've used ACL for probably 10+ years and it seems to be very rock solid:

https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.permissions.acl.intro.html

The newer version is Laminas ACL:
https://docs.laminas.dev/laminas-permissions-acl/usage/

Yes you'll need to build a Library/Interface to the files but it is worth it.